# PHP get file modified or create date showing 1970

Tags: php, iis

Im running php 5.1 on a windows IIS server and its returning the filemtime and filectime date as 1970
 A ful date is shown as Jan 1 1970. These are files that were created this year. Im hoping to write a script that shows current month current yr files only as a filter for an end user. Any ideas on why its returning 1970?

Answer (score 0):

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time orEpoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number ofseconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Thank you @thefakeslimshady. I had a feeling it was something like that. Oddly, if I echo the current date in PHP it returns correctly. Its only if I request a file creation date or modified date that it returns in this format. Im curious why its returning Unix info on a windows IIS.